# Ember Multiselect onchange

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember HBS template with a multiselect that I need to update the model onchange.

For regular selects, I used the following

```
<select id="scCalibration" onchange={{action (mut model.someField) value="target.value"}}>
```

But for the multiselect, what I need is a comma delimited list of selected values updated in the model. I'd prefer not to use a third party library like Ember-Power-Select if possible. I can't seem to figure it out...

Comment: I tried this, you can have a look at this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/5232181d8c96c6530629e9238f20148a?openFiles=helpers.is-available.js%2C) we may need to implement the lots of edge cases I do want to know the reasoning behind your thought of not using the addon?. When starting in ember I do got the same thought like not using addons after some time I started using it,now I am using `@html-next/vertical-collection`,`ember-concurrency`,`ember-href-to`,`ember-moment`,`ember-power-select`,`ember-route-action-helper`,`ember-truth-helpers` .... all are serving their purpose really well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy way to do this without using a third party tool.

I added to the select

```
onchange={{action 'setMultiFieldModel'}}
```

Then in the conroller action

```
 setMultiFieldModel: function(){
    var model = this.get('model');
    var field_vals = $("#field").val().join();
    var record_id = model.foo + '_' + model.bar;
    var rec = this.store.peekRecord('model-name', record_id, { backgroundReload: false });
    rec.set('field', field_vals);
  },
```